# Calling Oracle function from SQL Server does nore return results

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

I want to call an Oracle Function from SQL Server (oracle is a linked server).

Oracle function

```
create or replace function myfunction (p in nvarchar2) return nvarchar2 is
begin
  return p;
 end;
```

T-SQL Code

```
declare @inp nvarchar(max) = 'test';
declare @outp nvarchar(100);

EXECUTE ( 'begin ? := myfunction (?); end;', @outp output, @inp) AT MegaOracle
print  @outp
```

Problem is I don't get any result....
No errors - just no results.

Thank U
Andreas

Comment: Show how you created the Linked Server. One other thing you can try, is just perform a select on that function. select linkedservername.myfunction('test');

Comment: >>>select linkedservername.myfunction('test') is not correct.

Getting Error:  Cannot find either column "MegaOracle" or the user-defined function or aggregate "MegaOracle.myfunction", or the name is ambiguous.

Comment: Also linked server must be ok as it works well with openqueury